# How do i simplify this $\cos{\theta}=\frac{1-\sin^2{\theta}}{1+\cos{\theta}}$

Tags: trigonometry

I was wondering if someone could help me solve this equation: $$\cos{\theta}=\frac{1-\sin^2{\theta}}{1+\cos{\theta}}$$

Comment: It's best for you to show what you have tried so far.  If you put lots of efforts for this problem, I may provide the answer to you.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do it is why I posted without trying the steps.

Comment: See the answer for steps to work out this problem.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Multiply both sides by $1 + \cos(\theta)$.  Use the following identity: $1 - \sin^2(\theta) = \cos^2(\theta)$.  Then, rearrange the terms of $\cos$ to obtain the equation of the form

$$a\cos^2(\theta) + b\cos(\theta) = 0$$

Finally, factor the expression and use zero-product property to find $\theta$.

Answer (score 0):

$\cos{\theta}=\dfrac{1-\sin^2{\theta}}{1+\cos{\theta}}$:

1.)  Multiply through by $1 + \cos \theta$:

$\cos \theta + \cos^2 \theta = 1 - \sin^2 \theta$;

2.)  Add $\sin^2 \theta$ to each side:

$\cos \theta + \cos^2 \theta + \sin^2 \theta = 1$;

3.)  Use $\cos^2 \theta + \sin^2 \theta = 1$ on the left:

$\cos \theta + 1 = 1$;

4.)  Subtract $1$ throughout:

$\cos \theta = 0$:

5.)  Deduce from item (4) that $\theta$ must be an odd multiple of $\pi / 2$:  $\theta = (2n + 1)\pi / 2$ for $n$ an integer.

And that's it!

Hope this helps!  Cheerio,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Comment: Okay, but how would I solve if the 1 isn't attached to the sin^2 theta? The equation should read cos theta= 1- (sin^2 theta)/(1+cos theta)

Comment: @Tee:  you mean $\cos \theta = 1 - \dfrac{\sin^2 \theta}{1 + \cos \theta}$?

Comment: Yes, Robert. That's exactly it. Wasn't sure how to do the fraction bar to split it. I know what the identities state but not sure what my first move would be to simplifying the equation.

Comment: @Tee:  I think this last one is an identity!  If you multiply through by $1 + \cos \theta$, and add $\sin^2 \theta$, what do you get?

Comment: After multiplying by 1+ cos theta on the right I was left with cos theta= 1-sin^2theta. And that's where I get stuck because I'm not sure if you are splitting the 1-sin^2 into (sin theta)(sin theta).

Comment: @Tee:  If you multiply through by $1 + \cos \theta$, don't you get $\cos \theta + \cos^2 \theta = 1 + \cos \theta - \sin^2 \theta$?

Comment: I was under the impression based of what the teacher told us that you only work with one side when trying to get them to equal the portion on the opposite side of the equal sign. The answer should be cos theta = cos theta. And that you don't do anything to the opposite side not being worked on.

Comment: @Tee:  I'm sorry, but I don't what to say about what your teacher said, but I think my solutions are mathematically valid!  I always figure any operation is OK if it is well-defined and rigorous, whether it works on one side or both!

Comment: @ Robert, I don't know what to say either. Thanks for all of your help with this problem.

Comment: @Tee:  sure, glad to help out!

Answer (score 0):

Let $c=\cos(\theta)$, $s=\sin(\theta)$.  We have $c+c^2=1-s^2\iff c+c^2=c^2\iff c=0\iff \theta=2k\pi$.